# How to return the first n-1 elements of a list of length n in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tail

I know about the tail function that returns the last n-1 elements of a list (where n is the length of the list), so I defined my own "cotail" function to return the first n-1 elements:

```
cotail = (reverse . tail . reverse)
```

Is this the best way, or is there a builtin function or a cleverer way to achieve this?

Comment: BTW, "returns the last _n_ - 1 elements" is not really a great description. Generally, lengths are not a good property for lists, since they may be infinite (and even when they aren't, `length` is unnecessarily expensive because it needs to traverse the entire list). Better say simply "`tail` returns all elements except for the `head`". Likewise, `init` returns all elements except for the `last` one.

Comment: True, but it serves the purpose, i.e. everybody understands my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [init](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3ainit).

Answer (score 8):

As the others have said, `init` is what you're looking for. But here is how you can answer questions of the form "Is there a Haskell function to do X?" in general:

1. Figure out what the type signature of the function you want would be. In this case, we would expect the type signature to be `[a] -> [a]`.
2. Search [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=) or [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=). If you don't find it in one, try the other. Usually it doesn't matter much whether you get the order of the input parameters exactly right, but you may need to experiment.

Doing this search on Hayoo just now, `init` shows up as the third result for me.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about these search engines, that's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Use `init`, as has been advised. But you need to be sure what you do with empty lists.

```
cotail xs = [x | x:_:_ <- tails xs]
```

This version of `cotail` does not fail on empty lists, like `drop 1` doesn't fail on empty lists (whereas `tail` does)

Answer (score 1):

The init function which does exactly what you need.